# Slice certain number of elements from array only if they meet certain condition

Tags: arrays, extjs, extjs4, slice

Ext.Array.slice() is used to grab a range of elements from given `begin` and `end` figure. I'm slicing out 10 elements from a large array.

Now, I'd like to slice 10 elements from the array which meet certain condition (like passing a function to `slice()` which returns truthy value), instead of grabbing 10 values directly. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of ExtJs are you using? If you are on version 4 or above checkout the Array.filter method.

E.g.

```
function isBigEnough(element, index, array) {
  return (element >= 10);
}

passed = [12, 5, 8, 1, 4,15].filter(isBigEnough);
//returns [12,15]
```

Comment: I'm currently relying on a workaround to get it working, for Ext version, refer to my question tags.

Comment: So does the solution I provided do what you need?